# Can I differentiate "all" vs specific debian arch in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, debian, deb

I'm working on a private build system that produces debian packages using a toplevel Makefile. By including /usr/share/dpkg/default.mk, I get the package name and version from debian/control and debian/changelog. There is also $(DEB_TARGET_ARCH), which would be useful, except it isn't smart enought to notice if the package is "all" architecture.
Is there an official way to get the package arch at build time?
As it stands I need 2 versions. One for arch (e.g. "amd64") packages and one for "all"

Here is the top of my Makefile

```
include /usr/share/dpkg/default.mk

DEB_PKG := ../$(DEB_SOURCE)_$(DEB_VERSION)_all.deb
my_stuff := blabity blah and so forth

all:

deb: $(DEB_PKG)

$(DEB_PKG): debian $(my_stuff)
        gbp buildpackage --git-ignore-new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can determine in the general case whether a Debian package build will produce only architecture-independent packages.  You have to run `debian/rules binary` and see what that produces.  Even packages listed in `debian/control` might not actually be built in the end.

Comment: Yes, your right. The Architecture is package specific, you'd have to parse it out of one of the package sections in debian/control. I'm probably fighting with the system by trying to automate my deb builds from the Makefile